# Detect QRCode using AVCaptureSession and AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode worked in xCode 8, but not xCode 9

Tags: qr-code, avcapturesession, ios11, xcode9

I am was to detect QRCode using AVCaptureSession and AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode when using Xcode 8 iOS 10, now it won't detect the QR codes when compiled with xCode 9 iOS 11.  Can anyone help! I don't understand what changed.

Thanks in advance,

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here if anyone else runs into this.

[AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate has been renamed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011211/barcode-on-swift-4)

Basically Apple renamed the AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate.